# Get Url Parameter from Request and store it in variable in apache config

Tags: apache2

In my apache config, I want to allow access only when a specific url parameter matches a specific cookie.

I imagine a solution looking similar to this (in pseudocode):

```
param = get_url_parameter_with_a_specific_name_from_request  

if (!http_cookie_includes_a_cookie_named_<param>) {
 Require all denied
}
```

How can I implement that?

---

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /myparam=abc/> 
  <If "${HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /abc=1/">
    Require all granted
  </If>
  <Else>
    Require all denied
  </Else>
</If>
<Elseif "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /myparam=def/> 
  <If "${HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /def=1/">
    Require all granted
  </If>
  <Else>
    Require all denied
  </Else>
</Elseif>
<Elseif "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /myparam=ghi/> 
  <If "${HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /ghi=1/">
    Require all granted
  </If>
  <Else>
    Require all denied
  </Else>
</Elseif>
<Elseif "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /myparam=whatever/> 
  <If "${HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /whatever=1/">
    Require all granted
  </If>
  <Else>
    Require all denied
  </Else>
</Elseif>
...
```

How can I write this without mentioning the `whatever` part specificyally but using a variable instead?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure if I understood your question correctly.

I used this a while ago to semi secure a site:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Allow access when the GET parameter t=let_me_in is set and set a cookie
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /t=let_me_in$/">
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "/?t=authorized" [R,CO=ALLOWED:YES:dev.example.com]
</If>
# Allow access when the cookie is set
<ElseIf "%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /ALLOWED/">
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "-" [CO=ALLOWED:YES:dev.example.com]
</ElseIf>
# Reject everybody else
<Else>
    Require all denied
</Else>
```

If the query string of a request contains a specific token (in this case `t=let_me_in` a cookie named `ALLOWED` is set with the value `YES`.

If this cookie is set the access is allowed, otherwise it is denied.

Every time an authorized request is made the cookie is set again to extend its lifetime.

Comment: My question is about whether I can obtain dynamically a value from the url parameter and then check, whether a cookie with that name exists.

Comment: It's about semi security as well.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The only variable I can find is `%{QUERY_STRING}`, the URL parameters don't exist as separate variables. I don't see any way to split this up.

Comment: If I already have both strings (query string and http cookie) in the config, there must be a way of comparing them the way I want. This is a very simple string comparison operation and apache is supposed to be very powerful.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide what you already have, it saves people to start from scratch.

Comment: I don't have anything I can show yet.

Comment: I want to process a specific pattern of http requests only in case a specific url parameter value matches a cookie and deny it otherwise.